# How to enable gzip compression for specific directory and tell browsers to cache it's contents?

Tags: jetty, oracle-apex, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, oracle-ords

I am using Oracle's ORDS 20.2 which has jetty/9.4.28.v20200408 embedded, APEX 20.1, Database 18c XE, Google Chrome Version 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit), opera Version:70.0.3728.106
and Windows 7 Ultimate.

In APEX there is a directory that has APEX's static files - CSS and Javascript files and image files. I need to enable gzip for that directory and tell the browser to cache it for at least 12 hours in order to improve performance for APEX development environment and my APEX applications according to Oracle's documentation here, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmig/performance-optimization-tasks.html#GUID-668ED330-AFDC-4A43-AA11-D67FCCA58DA1

I've created a folder named "etc" under the "standalone" folder of my ORDS configuration directory. That's the folder where I should put any Jetty's Xml configuration files. Then created a file called "jetty.xml" with the following contents to implement what is in the Jetty's documentation about sending Cache-Control header,
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/header-filter.html And

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>  
    <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"   
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">  
    <filter>  
       <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>  
       <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.HeaderFilter</filter-class>  
       <init-param>  
         <param-name>headerConfig</param-name>  
         <param-value>  
          "add Cache-Control: max-age=43200"  
         </param-value>  
       <init-param>  
         <param-name>includedPaths</param-name>  
         <param-value>  
          "D:\ords\images"  
         </param-value>  
       </init-param>  
     </filter>
```

But when I run ORDS through a batch file which has

```
    cd D:\Original\Oracle_ORDS_Editions\ords-20.2.0.178.1804
    d:
    java -jar ords.war standalone
```

the cmd window opens then vanishes automatically.
I need to know why the code fails and still need to enable gzip for that directory. Thank you.

Comment: Jetty 9.4.28 is subject to a high severity security vulnerability - would strongly recommend upgrading - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security-reports.html

Comment: I can not. It's embedded into ORDS.

Answer (score 1):

The `HeaderFilter` is for use with webapps that are traditionally deployed via a webapp archive (WAR file).

The documented configuration for `HeaderFilter` is for the war internal `WEB-INF/web.xml` servlet descriptor that is specific to the webapp being deployed (typically found within a WAR file).

Arbitrarily creating `etc` directories and `jetty.xml` files are never a relevant form of configuration for Jetty.

The `etc` directory and the `jetty.xml` concepts are only relevant if you are using the standalone Jetty techniques (such as what's seen in `jetty-home` or the older `jetty-distribution` archives).  More specifically, the `start.jar` within the `jetty-home` archive is the only one that looks for and uses either the `etc` directory or the `jetty.xml` file.

The `jetty.xml`, that the `start.jar` is aware, of is never managed by manually creating it or editing it.  In fact it's a typically a read-only file that comes with the `jetty-home` archive, and is used in-place.  The `etc` directory is found within the `jetty-home` archive, and can also be seen in the application specific configuration of Jetty standalone known as the `${jetty.base}` directory.

You mentioned "jetty/9.4.28.v20200408 embedded" which typically means it's not using the standalone Jetty concepts.  In an embedded Jetty scenario, the configuration of the Jetty server is typically done within the configuration techniques of the parent project (Oracle ORDS in your case).  You'll need to know how that Jetty server is configured, and work within the limits of whatever configuration that parent project provides to you.

Comment: I got the "etc" part from Jeff Smith's article thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/06/… . "Embedded" is a word used by him. He is "a senior principal product manager in Oracle’s Database Development Tools group, and is responsible for Oracle REST Data Services." Regarding the Xml file name, actually, I am not sure about the name it should hold. In the article above he named it jetty-http.xml and I have seen  jetty.xml in another article/thread by another poster on the web. Unfortunately, I do not know the rule. I appreciate your help regarding this point too.